# Matching and update complex data mongodb object inside array inside object inside array inside object working with complex data

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, pattern-matching

I hava a mongo object that's looking like this

```js
[{
    username: "user1",
    id: "1",
    Notifications: {
      history: {
        Messages: [Object],
        Collections: [{
            Post: "text here",
            likes: [{
                likedID: 8997,
                like: false
              },
              {
                likedID: 988890,
                like: false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Comment: "text here",
            likes: [{
                likedID: 6898554,
                like: false
              },
              {
                likedID: 333554321,
                like: false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    username: "user2",
    id: "2",
    Notifications: {
      history: {
        Messages: [Object],
        Collections: [{
          Post: "text here",
          likes: [{
              likedID: 1245,
              like: false
            },
            {
              likedID: 5675,
              like: false
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

i need to find and updata the value of like inside the object where `likedID` is `1245`

How can i do that in mongodb

Here's what i have tried

```js
db.user.update({
  "Notifications..history.Collections": {
    "$all": [{
      "$elemMatch": {
        likes: {
          "$all": [{
            "$elemMatch": {
              likedID: 1245
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}, {
  "$set": {
    "Notifications.history.Collections.$.likes": {
      like: true
    }
  }
})
```

I searched a lot but i can't find the solution and it's really complicated so how can i perform this task

Comment: The two objects in your post don't match, is it `Notifications.history.Collections` or `Notifications.Collections`?

Comment: Ok i edited it to set `history` in the second object

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying across two arrays, you need the positional filter operator and arrayFilter option. You also need something to identify the "parent" of the like, here I use `Post` - but probably you want something like postID.

You can read more here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#std-label-position-nested-arrays-filtered

```js
db.user.update(
 {"Notifications.history.Collections.Post": "text here"},
 {
  $set: {
   "Notifications.history.Collections.$.likes.$[like].liked": false
  }
 },
 { arrayFilters: [{ "like.likedID": 1245 }] } 
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work bro i still can't figure how to match and update it